# How to get reference of textfield in target method in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have added target on `UITextField` of `UITableViewCell`.I have used below code for that.

```
  cellIdentifier  = @"TextFieldCell";
      TextFieldCell *txtCell  = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
      txtCell.indexPath = indexPath;
      [txtCell.textFieldData addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

Now for in target method described as below.

```
-(void)textFieldDidChange :(UITextField *) textField{


}
```

I have added `indexpath` property in below TextCell.In callback method i want to get the refrence of textfield on which i have added target so that i can access the `indexpath` property.
I want to get the `txtCell.textFieldData` in the callback method.Please tell me how can i do this ?

Comment: `textField` in `textFieldDidChange ` is reference of `txtCell.textFieldData`.

Comment: in textFieldDidChange , textfield is the your selected textfield reference .

Comment: You can use tag property of textfield

Answer (score 1):

add one or more line in your tableview datasource method for find the which textfield you selected or identify which textfield you tapped

```
txtCell.textFieldData.delegate = self;
txtCell.textFieldData.tag = indexPath.row;
txtCell.textFieldData.text = [self.yourarrayName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[txtCell.textFieldData addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

on your action you can get the reference of your current textfield

```
-(void)textFieldDidChange :(UITextField *) textField{

    NSLog(@"textField values== %%@",textField);
}
```

**update and example**

if you want to update the textfield, then follow like

```
-(void)textFieldDidChange :(UITextField *) textField{

    NSLog(@"this is your current textfield values== %%@",textField);
    [self.yourarrayName replaceObjectAtIndex:textField.tag withObject:textField.text];
if (textField.text.length > 0)
{
    [textField setNeedsDisplay];
    // do something whatever you need
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could sublass your `UITextField` to contain a property of type `NSIndexPath`.

```
@interface MRTextField : UITextField

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSIndexPath *indexPath

@end
```

In your storyboard/xib just select the `UITextField` and change its class to `MRTextField`. Create an outlet for this textfield in your `TextFieldCell` and it will be of the type `MRTextField` instead of `UITextField`. From your storyboard <kbd>control</kbd> + drag your text field to the `UIViewController` and set it as the delegate.

Then just implement the delegate method of the `UITextField` `shouldChangeCharactersInRange`

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

    MRTextField *tempTextField = (MRTextField *)textField;

   //access the indexPath property using tempTextField.indexPath

    return YES;
}
```

**Note:** The textfield doesn't have the latest change the user performed in the above delegate method, for example if he typed in *s* the `textfield.text` will contain text **before** the *s* has been added to the string. You can either add it on your own and save to the model in the above method or perform your operations in the following delegate:

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

    MRTextField *tempTextField = (MRTextField *)textField;

   //access the indexPath property using tempTextField.indexPath

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to give tag to textfield of perticular cell then in target method you can get that tag and then use following :

```
TextFieldCell *txtCell = [tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:tag]
```

Now you can access ---  txtCell.textFieldData